# Cordova app for FireOs doesn't use system volume

Tags: cordova, web-audio-api

I have a web-app that produces sound using the WebAudio API and have used cordova to make it into an amazon FireOS native app. The only problem is that the system volume of the kindle fire tablet has no effect on the app's audio output. Even with the system volume all the way off, the app still plays sound at the same unchangeable volume (which is too quiet to be usable). Why is this?